# Internet disconnects intermittently using Realtek RTL8111

Tags: 12.10, networking, internet, realtek

The broadband Ethernet connection stops to work or rather stays connected but stops loading pages and showing content on the Internet with a *server not found* error. The connection information states the Internet is connected with a correct IP configuration but still the surfing problems occur quite frequently and suddenly starts working after few minutes.

How can this be resolved?

*On running*: `sudo lshw -C network`

```
 *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 07
       serial: d4:be:d9:2a:16:09
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 ip=115.252.220.236 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:42 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:c1404000-c1404fff memory:c1400000-c1403fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Wireless-N 2230
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: c4
       serial: 68:5d:43:45:67:4e
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.8.0-6-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:47 memory:c1500000-c1501fff
```

Comment: I think [this](http://unixblogger.wordpress.com/2011/10/18/the-pain-of-an-realtek-rtl8111rtl8168-ethernet-card/) would help you.